# How to stop closing JFrame form?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-7, windowlistener

I want to Stop accidentally closings in my project. I'm using JFrame Form as Home page. When I click Home window's close button I put Exit cord in Yes Option. I want to stop closing when I click No Option. Is there any way. Here is my cord. I'm using netbeans 7.3

```
 private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
 int i= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to exit?");
    if (i == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else{
        new Home().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it ii. :( I can you same process using a button's action event. Should I use any event.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Wrong is when I'm clicking "No" or "Cancel" instead of "Yes" Still Home window is closing.

Comment: The "new Home().setVisible(true)" creates a new Home object; then its setVisible is called. This has no effect on the Home object that created the window that is closing.  The event should be called on that existing Home object.  You should be able to write instead "this.setVisible(true)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
class MyGUI extends JFrame {

    public MyGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);// <- don't close window 
                                                             // when [X] is pressed

        final MyGUI gui = this;
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(gui,
                        "Are you sure to exit?", "Closing dialog",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (i == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //demo
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gettin this error "Package Frame doen not exit" can you help with that?

Comment: @user2867987 `frame` is not package but instance of `JFrame` you want to prevent from closing. You can put this code in your `JFrame` class constructor/initialization and replace `frame` with `this` or even skip it.

Comment: @user2867987 I added some more context to my example.

Comment: I'm really sorry to say. Is this you are syaing? frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Home.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);// <- prevent closing
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
int i = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "Are you sure to exit?", "Closing dialog",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (i == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }                                  
}); Beacause it is not working.

Comment: I tried edited one too. Still I don't know where I should put final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);// <- prevent closing
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {});

Comment: @user2867987 I am not sure how you are using it. As I told you before `frame` holds reference to your main window on which you want to perform confirmation test so if you want to put this code in your class that represents main window then just remove `frame` (you can use `this` instead of skip it).

Comment: @user2867987 Please [[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19301510/edit)] your question and include code you are using now.

Comment: No this is worikng. Its ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that like this

```
Integer opt =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This application cannot continue without login to the database\n Are you sure you need to exit...?", "Application X", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(opt== JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
    this.setVisible(true);
}else{
    System.exit(0);
}
```